# Is it possible to assign a Series to a DataFrame and use the Series' name as column name?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Series `s` like this:

```py
0     6
1     0
2     0
3     8
4     8
5    10
6    10
7     9
Name: my_series, dtype: int64
```

and given a `df`, would it be possible to assign the series to the `df` without having
to specify a column name? (The Series name would be used instead)

So, I'd like to **avoid** having to do this explicitly:

```py
df['my_series'] = s # avoid
```

My mind goes to something like this:

```py
pd.concat([df, s.to_frame()], axis=1)
```

but I guess it is counterintuitive.

I have also thought of using `df.assign`, but I think it requires specifying a column name as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what's the problem with `pd.concat` solution? (Note: you don't need to transform series to dataframe to concat)

Comment: It gets its job done, but to my mind it kind of lacks the sense of having something assigned to the df. That's why I am trying to explore alternatives. If no such alternative was to be found, I would resort to using `pd.concat` instead! It's more of a visual concern :)

Comment: Series does have a name in itself, would a solution with `df.assign` work if you were not hard-coding the new column name, but assigning it from series? (e.g. `df.assign(**{s.name: s})`)?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! I really like the dict comprehension being unpacked, because it can be extended to work in other cases as well, such as: `df.assign(**{s.name: s for s in function_that_returns_tuple_of_series()})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`pandas.Series.name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html) in the first solution:

```py
df[s.name] = s
# or df.assign(**{s.name: s})
```

Note that this will override the column if the column with the same name is already present (unlike the `pd.concat` solution).

Another option - `df.join`:

```
df = df.join(s)
```

This one will throw in case of column with same name being present.

Comment: Not writing a separate answer, since this is a more informative answer, but this solution also works with `df.assign` as per comments bellow the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name':['12','13','14']})

s = pd.Series([0,1,2], name='my_series')

df = df.join(s)
print (df)
  col_name  my_series
0       12          0
1       13          1
2       14          2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.insert(1,"my_series",s)
```

Insert function enables to insert column into DataFrame at specified location, first argument shows where to insert a column second means column name and last your list or series

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I have edited post for more clear understanding. Thanks a lot for feedback.